# How to get data from database of current date

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

I want to get all data of current date from my database I'm using phpMyAdmin
this is the query which I use but it did not show any data

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE time = CURDATE();
```

[image: 1]

Comment: phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself. You are probably using MySQL or MariaDB as your DB. Your tags are completely wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, time) = CONVERT(DATE, time)
```

SQL Server is smart enough to use an index when converting a date/time to a date, so this is index-safe.

Your syntax is more reminiscent of MySQL.  In that database, the best solution is:

```
WHERE time >= curdate() AND
      time < curdate() + interval 1 day
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are using SQL Server, so this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM tables
WHERE convert(varchar(10), time, 102) = convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 102)
```

Answer (score 1):

try to convert your time to the date format

```
SELECT * FROM tables WHERE convert(time,getdate(), 101)  = CURDATE();
```

More about date converting: 
https://tableplus.io/blog/2018/09/ms-sql-server-how-to-get-date-only-from-datetime-value.html

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/